# Flip jQuery Modal Dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog, modal-dialog, flip

We have been using jQuery's modal dialog as a way for users to edit settings on a page. This works great.

Now, we would like to be able to "flip" the dialog over and have some additional (less-used) settings on its "backside".

We have tried using [Flip!](http://lab.smashup.it/flip) but have found that it hides the dialog after it is run and doesn't display our replacement content until we manually re-display the modal dialog again.

We've searched for any tutorials on this, but haven't had much luck.

Does anyone have any experience with "flipping" dialog boxes?  Any tips, links etc would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: be aware that element you call dialog on actually gets wrapped by outer elements...so need to target it's parent to do a flip

Comment: Yes, definitely.  I have tried targeting ".ui-dialog"  which does create the flip animation, but flips it away to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to have some more effects on Twitter Modal Dialog you can go for CSS Transition effects. Tympanus provides some great CSS effects.

I don't know why creator of this effect named it "Nifty Modal Dialog Box" You can have its source code and demo from here: [Tympanus Nifty Modal](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/25/nifty-modal-window-effects/)